# Django + Adsense on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates, adsense

I have a problem with Django on Google App Engine. I finished to design html templet for my web application and I imported them on django using django template system. 
The problem is google ad-sense. I can say ad-sense banner on the html version of my pages if i try to open them in my browser. But nothing appear if I try to do the same operation with them loaded in django. 
I also tried to develop a simple html template that contains only the adSense script, if i load this on django it returns a white page. No banner, nothing. 
What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you could show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

adsense is javascript, if your django is returning nothing check your HttpResponse and how you are generating the template. it looks like you need to specify in settings.py the location of the template file.

you may want add the following (in settings.py):

```
import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates')
)
```

then put your django templates in a sub-directory to your project called "/templates"

or try the process of elimination:
comment out any javascript and see if you can generate the template from django.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! Sorry, I accidentally added some character with erroneous codeing.